# tensorflow: tf.set_random_seed() same code, but got different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, horovod

**In short, in tensorflow, except for tf.set_random_seed(), is there any other config I should set to reproduce the same result? no numpy operation in my code.**

Long version:
I am training a model with horovod, and I want to reproduce the results for debug. I set tf.set_random_seed(1) before build the graph. All operations are in tensorflow, no numpy.

And I just rerun the training script for several times, code has not been modified.

As I understand, they should produce the same results, since the graph is build by the same order and the random_seed is set the same. The session.run order will not cause the different, not to mention I didn't change the code.

However, I still got different results for the same code on multiple runs.

Specifically, I can see the input image is read by the same order, and the step 'tf.image.random_flip_left_right' produce random flip with the same seed.

But I test the tf.image.random_flip_left_right by the following code, which gives the same results. So there is no bug in this function. It did accept the global tf random_seed and produce same results.

```
import tensorflow as tf                                                                                                              
tf.set_random_seed(0)
img_raw =tf.read_file('test.jpg')
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img_raw,channels=3,dct_method='INTEGER_ACCURATE')
image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)

sess=tf.Session()
print(sess.run(image))
```

How can it be random flip with the same seed and graph? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set the seed in `tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image, seed = 0)` and test?

**EDIT**

okay, you said you are not using numpy in the code but TF uses it for some internal tasks. So, can you again try and this time fixing the numpy seed too.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import seed
seed(0)
```

If this doesn't also work then maybe the problem is with `Horovod` as talked about it [here](https://github.com/horovod/horovod/issues/173#issuecomment-369247966).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Strange, even I set seed=0, this operation still produces different result within 2 run.

Comment: Why not?. [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) is the official documentation.

Comment: sorry, I mean it still produce different result. I set numpy.random.seed(0) right after tf.set_random_seed()

Comment: Then it must be because of Horovod or something else that you are missing in your code. Also, try it on some other machine without Horovod.

Comment: OK, thank you. Now I am digging into the batching.map_and_batch operation. The random flip is in "process_fn" in this operation. I am thinking the random number is generated by the order, which is related to the data processing progress. I would update if there is any conclusion.